# Variables not updating outside function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So, I have two controllers (they have been reduced for simplicity) with one function each. The functions change a variable inside each of the controllers. The thing is, it looks like only the variable in the first controller is updated.

app.js

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('ScBO', []);
  var token = {};

  app.controller("LoginController", ['$http', function($http){
    this.userData = {};
    var lc = this;
    this.in = false;

    this.loginGo = function(){
      $http.post(<link>, <userData>)
      .then(function successCallback(response){
        token = response.data.access_token;
        lc.in=true;
      }, function errorCallback(response){
        lc.in=false;
      });
    };
  }]);

  app.controller("DashboardController", ['$http', function($http){
    var dsb = this;    
    this.totalLocals = 0;

    this.refresh = function(){
      $http.get('<link>?access_token='+token)
      .then(function successCallback(response){
        dsb.totalLocals = response.data.number_of_locals.number_of_locals;
      }, function errorCallback(response){
      });
    };
  }]);

})();
```

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="LoginController as loginCtrl">
  <div id="login-div" ng-hide="loginCtrl.in">
    <form ...>
   ...
    </form>
  </div>


  <div id="dashboard" ng-show="loginCtrl.in" ng-controller="DashboardController as dsb">
    <div class="numbers">
     <p>Number of Locals</p>
     {{dsb.totalLocals}}
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

So in the html, the first div appears in the beginning and not the second one. Then it hides and the second div shows up. This means that they are following the update of the loginCtrl.in variable.
However, when I call the refresh function, it doesn't update the value in the last div.

I've tried with $scope and have been searching in here but I haven't been able to find a solution yet. Specially since the two controllers are equal but only one of them seems to be updating the variables normally.

Comment: You sure ur `$http` req got resolved successfully ?

Comment: I did this plunkr trying to simulate your problem and for me its seems to be working: https://plnkr.co/edit/ySNl3t17vKMgaRKn8LR6?p=preview

Comment: @Rahul I've tried putting a console.log(response.data.number_of_locals.number_of_locals); after the assignment to the variable dsb.totalLocals and saw that the value coming from the server is the correct one.

Comment: @leonardoborges, The timeout function works and the value gets updated, but then why isn't it working inside the refresh function?

Comment: @Johnny you should check if the response is what you are expecting.

Comment: I did, I've put:
console.log("////// " +response.data.number_of_locals.number_of_locals);
console.log("////// " +dsb.totalLocals);
and they both say the right value inside the refresh function. But it still doens't update outside

Comment: @leonardoborges, I've made a change inside the plunkr. If you see, with a function: 
this.add = function(){
      dsb.totalLocals++;
    };
and the button calling this funtion, it doesn't work

Comment: have you tried declaring a new local variable inside of your 2nd controller and binding token to it, then using it like that ?

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović, just tried that. It doesn't copy the token to the new variable inside the 2nd controller. Can't understand why

Answer (score 0):

So, I've figured out the problem.
In the code above the error doesn't show as I only posted part of the code for simplicity, but I thought it was enough.

The thing was: I had the button that triggers the refresh function in a different div (like @leonardoborges ' plunkr). Like that two controllers are instantiated with their own values, something that I didn't know. The timeout function updates all instances of the controller, so that was confusing me.

So now I just put everything within one instance of the controller.